# Nginx - How to run multiple instance of Odoo with different subdomain names

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, odoo-10

I'd like to run two instance of Odoo v10 on different links.
the 1st instance will include multiple databases for our testing purposes running on this link mydoamin.com

And for the second instance will be holding demo databases for our clients to demonstrate Odoo for them on this link clients.mydomain.com

Both instances should be running on the same server.
I did a lot of research to figure out how to achieve this approach, but I didn't find any guide can help me to do it by using Nginx reverse proxy.

Here's my Nginx configuration file:

```
upstream backend-odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream backend-odoo-im { 
    server 127.0.0.1:8072; 
}
server {
    listen 80;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 default;
    # ssl settings
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;
    keepalive_timeout 60;

    #increase the upload file size limit
    client_max_body_size 300M;

    # proxy header and settings
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # odoo log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-error.log;
    # increase proxy buffer size
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500
    http_502 http_503;
    # enable data compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
    gzip_vary on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend-odoo;
    }
    location ~* /web/static/ {
    # cache static data
    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    proxy_buffering on;
    expires 864000;
    proxy_pass http://backend-odoo;
    }
    location /longpolling { 
        proxy_pass http://backend-odoo-im;
    }
}
```

PS. I tried to set `db filter = ^%d$` in odoo configuration file but it I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dbfilter = %h$` that works for me better.
You have to rename your databases that it matches the URL's.
yourdomain.com get yourdomain_com as DB name.